# Oracle SQL Developer - Combining Cartesian Product, Count/Sum and Group By

Tags: sql, oracle, cartesian-product

I am joining 2 tables using Cartesian Product as follows.

```
select p.type, i.amount 
FROM products p, invoice i
where (p.account = i.id); -- column headers cant be changed despite having same info
```

This of course displays 2 columns with the respective values.

However I then want to manipulate the data further using COUNT/GROUP BY and SUM/GROUP BY but have been unable to find any relevant examples which I could get to work using 2 tables. (doing them all separately is ok, just getting them to work together is the problem).

For the end result, I want to show 3 columns showing a grouping of the 4 types, with the count of the entries falling under each type, and the total amount/SUM for each type, eg.

Type -  Count of Types -   Total Value

A  -      5            -   500

B  -      6            -  1000

C  -      1            -    50

D  -      2            -   100

Comment: What queries have you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: your query is not a cartesian product anymore. it's an inner join operation already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
select p.type, count(p.type) Cnt, sum(i.amoumt) Total
FROM products p, invoice i
where (p.account = i.id)
group by p.type
```

Comment: This work perfectly. I'd tried out very similar things already but didnt realise how close I was to a solution... Thanks

Comment: Note that if you want the result to be ordered by p.type then it's not sufficient to rely on any accidental ordering you get with the GROUP BY clause. You need to explicitly use ORDER BY, as a GROUP BY does not always sort.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that the result of a query is logically equivalent to a table or a view -- all of them are a projection of zero or more rows with one or more columns.

In general what you can do to a table in terms of select you can also do to a query or a view. Despite some limitations you can also apply deletes and updates to views and queries just as you can to a table.

If in doubt, create the query that returns the data you want, and then treat it as a table:

```
select   type,
         count(type) count_type,
         sum(amount) sum(amount)
from     (select ... )
group by type
```

Note also the subquery factoring clause, which has particular appplications if you need to reference the same logical data set multiple times:

```
with my_data as(
    select ... )
select   type,
         count(type) count_type,
         sum(amount) sum(amount)
from     my_data
where    type in (select ... from my_data)
group by type
```